# gdal_translate не работает

Tags: linux, apache, геолокация

Когда я вызываю команду через ssh console под root всё работает, но когда вызываю из программы, то есть с правами пользователя apache, не работает. Вот команда

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" \
   /opt/path/path/TCSHAPE/11-38-137-\(109-3\).tif \
   /opt/path/path/TCSHAPE/all/TCSHAPE.tif
```

Comment: Попробуйте записать сообщение, которое gdal_translate выводит в stderr. На каком языке вы программируете?

Comment: Может быть пользователь `apache` не имеет прав на запись в директорию `/opt/path/path/TCSHAPE/all`?